# Creating an address locator/geocoding addresses in ArcMap without using City or Placename

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, geocoding

I am creating an address locator, and I have it working, but if I want to search for any address, I have to enter the entire address into the search. I want to be able to enter everything besides the City or Placename, but I can't seem to make it work. 95% of my addresses are rural addresses located within a Canadian municipality, so the City or Placename field is superfluous, since we use a grid system for our road network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. I had to enable "Match with no zones" in the Geocoding Options. I edited the .xml file so this would always be enabled.

Here's a link to the ESRI page about it.

http://support.esri.com/EN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40678